# Use of "precision_step" in elasticsearch mappings

Tags: lucene, elasticsearch

In elastic search mapping there is an optional field called precision_step. What it means .
I searched in google . i cant find any solid info about.

Can anyone please explain what is a precision_step and use of it..!

thanks in advance..!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is part of the mapping for [dates](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-core-types.html#date) and [numbers](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-core-types.html#number).

It is a Lucene concept, you can read more here: [Lucene doco](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_3_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/NumericRangeQuery.html#precisionStepDesc)

From the Lucene Doco:

> Good values for precisionStep are depending on usage and data type:
>
> - The default for all data types is 4, which is used, when no precisionStep is given.
> - Ideal value in most cases for 64 bit data types (long, double) is 6 or 8.
> - Ideal value in most cases for 32 bit data types (int, float) is 4.
> - For low cardinality fields larger precision steps are good. If the cardinality is < 100, it is fair to use Integer.MAX_VALUE (see below).

Comment: i know its part of mapping.I need to know its use.. i surfed the link you provided.but i cant understand it clearly.Can u tell me an example to understand it.pls

Answer (score 2):

Suitable values are between 1 and 8. A good starting point to test is 4, which is the default value for all Numeric* classes.

Actual usage is, **Lower values consume more disk space but speed up searching**. Lower step values mean more precision and so more terms in index (and index gets larger).